# Baffled by nil results in ruby-dbi Oracle query

Tags: sql, ruby, oracle

I've not played with Ruby in a while, and was just writing a simple db query tool.

The tool connects fine and returns the correct number of results for the query (56 rows in this case), but the value returned for each element is 'nil'. Executing the query in sqlplus works fine.

I've found similar problems on StackExchange, but most of the solutions don't apply, or require using ODBC directly. Ugh.

I'm including a stripped down version of what I've written. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
require 'dbi'

dbh = DBI.connect('DBI:OCI8:foodb', 'user', 'password')
rs = dbh.prepare('select field_name from foo_user.cdr_fields where layout like ?')
rs.execute('phi_outage')
while rsRow = rs.fetch do
   p rsRow
end
rs.finish
dbh.disconnect
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the individual fields instead of printing the whole row? E.g. `printf rsRow[0]`.

Comment: That was it. I just needed to print the field.

Answer (score 3):

The fetch method is an iterator so no need for a while loop. Try

```
rs.fetch do|row|
  p row unless p.nil?
end
```

The API states that the method gets called for all remaining rows and will return nil when done.